# WebRTC Xamarin Binding for iOS - to wrap Objective C or C++ library?

Tags: c#, c++, ios, webrtc, xamarin-binding

I'm integrating WebRTC in a Xamarin.IOS app, and working through making the required C# bindings for the WebRTC library.

All of the info I've found on the web involves wrapping the Objective C framework with the help of Objective Sharpie, but the WebRTC iOS/MacOS framework seems to only be an Objective C wrapper around the internal C++ WebRTC library, so my question is:

Won't I be better off using P/Invoke around the native WebRTC C++ library and cutting the Objective C part out of it? Has anyone done this, and how?

I'll be doing an Android version of the app next. If I make a Xamarin Binding for the C++ lib, will I be able to use the same binding project for both iOS and Android versions of my app?

Comment: Do you have a github repo? This repo may be helpful https://github.com/valentingrigorean/apprtc-ios-xamarin

Comment: Yes, I have a copy of that repo. It has a binding to the iOS framework only (incidentally, I can only get it working on a device and not the simulator), but not a Binding I can share between iOS and Android

Comment: Great, I am not sure if you can share a single Binding with iOS & Android. Can you please share the working Bindings?

Comment: Have a look at this repo - https://github.com/Onotseike/Xamarin-WebRTC-Tutorial - There are some good progress being made there for making WebRTC work with Xamarin. And about using same binding for both android and iOS - No, you can't do that. You need the native library at the core of the binding dll to get it working in the respective OS.